# Install custom font

Tags: android, fonts

I have seen android applications once installed on any Android device, I can see new fonts coming to Settings and I can set the system font to what it had installed. How to write such an application so that I can setup unicode for Sinhala with my MalithiWeb.ttf? I have the ttf. I have experience in writing Android apps.

Found the answer myself. Thanks guys for your replies!
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755472

Comment: [This link may solve your problem](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/).

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. I need to add my own font to System fonts list.

Comment: Found the answer myself. Thanks guys for your replies! http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the instructions here:
http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

I'm pretty sure it works just as well with ttf.  I use TTF in my apps all the time, but I'm drawing them manually (not via XML), however, I think it works the same way under the hood.

Comment: It does not allow you to set the system font right? I need to build an apk myself which allows me to add my own fonts to System fonts list.

Comment: are you saying you want to overwrite the system font, so that without specifying any font at all it will just default to some alternate font? I don't believe you can do that.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite. I just need to add one more item into the existing list. It is doable using http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755472